# How can I create a list that add values from a table located in the same sheet but with different location

Tags: vba

I want to create a table that allows me to extract information from a table located in the same sheet but this new table is able to add similar values (All letters A with its respective volume, which is located in the following column)

I've tried to create a table that extract the data but I connot make a sum of the similar values (the same thing that a pivot table does)

Comment: Can you share some sample input/table and what you would want this result to look like. It's not clear from just your text.

Comment: Sub Stock_Values()
   Dim Ticker As String
   Dim Stock_Total As Double
  Stock_Total = 0
  Dim Summary_Table_Row As Integer
  Summary_Table_Row = 2
   For i = 2 To 760191
  If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
           Ticker = Cells(i, 1).Value
           Stock_Total = Stock_Total + Cells(i, 7).Value
           Range("J" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Ticker
           Range("K" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Stock_Total
           Summary_Table_Row = Summary_Table_Row + 1
Stock_Total = 0
Else
Stock_Total = Stock_Total + Cells(i, 7).Value
End If
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code in. Highlight what was pasted and click the `{}` button at the top to format as code. It's unreadable in a comment.